# Orks and Chaos? What? 40K

Tags: warhammer-40k

So I was looking in the rules, and I saw that Chaos and Orks are Allies of Convenience. Does this have any canon backing? I mean, fluff-wise. Sorry.

Comment: The rules aren't canon?

Comment: (1/2) I think that Allies of Convenience has to understood in a very broad sense. Two forces that can stay without fighting each other for a sufficient time in order to beat a common ennemy are Allies of Convenience (I would more have called it allies of circumstances). They don't need to share plans and strategical meetings, their general don't need to share the same ideology or ultimate goal, they don't even need to share space on the battlefield... This require the minimum level of "trust" (a reasonable understanding on how the other will behave at short term) between the two armies.

Comment: (2/2) In the vast galaxy of 40k, this leaves many options: imagine a Khorne band and a Ork band that agree to join their forces to attack a huge Imperial army, in order to make the battle last longer, for the pleasure of both allies. You can also consider an Alpha Legion force manipulating an Ork warband, or an Iron Warrior band using its artillery while its Ork allies fight their common opponent in close combat, etc. I don't post it as an answer as I guess you are looking for a specific example from the fluff.

Comment: I dont understand this question! The rules are canon... what more proof do you need? If Games Workshop says something it is so!!

Comment: They probably have a cannon backing...

Comment: @SQB that'd be Kannon for the orks. ;)  Anyway *really old* fluff there actually were Chaos Orks as a possible thing you could get through the Freebooterz supplement.  Fun times.